# Iterating files in a directory without using FindFirstFile

Tags: windows, winapi, file, directory, loops

On the Windows operating system, how do you iterate the files in a given directory without the use of third-party libraries or the use of FindFirstFile, FindNextFile, etc?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's wrong with FindFirstFile?

Comment: Make a screenshot of the Explorer window and OCR it?  Win32 does not routinely provide two separate ways to get the exact same job done.

Comment: @Hans there's more than one way to skin a cat, as the proverb says :). Explorer, as far as I know (*I can be mistaken here*) bypasses FindFirstFile and calls lower-level functions directly.

Comment: @Martinho, Hans, and peterchen, I have an application that can list the files in a directory and I am trying to figure out how it's doing it, because it doesn't use FindFirstFile, even though it's listed in the imports section of the DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that FindFirstFile is the main file enumeration method in Windows, what else do you expect to get? There are NT API functions (ZwQueryDirectoryFile and similar), which are called by FindFirstFile, but they are more complicated and don't give real benefit.

Comment: Not a real benefit? For starters you can use an APC, but better yet the native function can and will return as many entries as it can fit into the passed buffer (assuming `ReturnSingleEntry` is `FALSE`). This results in less function calls and should be a lot faster in general. Perhaps not quite as fast as doing it using MFT parsing, however.

Comment: @0xc0000022l Do you have some numbers? I saw several people trying to optimize directory scanning and their results were not that promising. But maybe this was OS-specific.  ZwQueryDirectoryFile seemed to be not much faster (I understand and back your point about using one call for multiple entries). Direct parsing of FAT or MFT does make difference, of course.

Comment: The problem is this method too slow for network drives, in my case it gets more than 10-20 minutes. But work fine when i go to the same directory through Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use managed code the programming is a little easier with [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx).

> Returns an enumerable collection of
>   file names in a specified path.

Answer (score 0):

The only additional way which i know to list the files in a directory is using the [`Scripting.FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object which is part of the Windows Scripting library. you can use this object in C++, delphi or any language which supports access to COM.

check this sample code in vbscript

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\test"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
Next
```