# Is there faster way to search for files with TDirectory.GetFiles or without it?

Tags: delphi

I need to do search on the `C:\` as fast as possible but because it has the many files from Windows 11 , program files and others folder the search take more than 30 seconds on SSD and much longer on HDD. Is there a faster way to do this ?

Here is the code I use:

```
procedure SearchForFiles(const ADirectory, AFileMask: string);
var
  FilesFound: TStringList;
  FileNames: TArray<string>;
  FileName: string;
begin
  FilesFound := TStringList.Create;
  try
    FileNames := TDirectory.GetFiles(ADirectory, AFileMask, TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
    for FileName in FileNames do
      FilesFound.Add(FileName);

    // Display the results in the memo
    Memo1.Lines.Assign(FilesFound);
  finally
    FilesFound.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I call it like this:

```
 Memo1.Clear; // Clear the memo before searching
  SearchForFiles('C:\', '*.txt');
```

Application is 64bit and I use Delphi 11

Comment: `TDirectory.GetFiles()` is slow, as it has to keep re-allocating the array that it returns for each file that it finds. You can mitigate some of that overhead by using a manual `FindFirst()`+`FindNext()` loop instead and save each file directly to your `TStringList`, but you will have to use your own recursive function to iterate through subfolders. And this approach might still not give you the level of performance that you are looking for. For the fastest possible iteration, you have to bypass the OS altogether and go straight to reading the filesystem tables directly, which is not trivial.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau Yes I also tried `FindFirst/FindNext` not fast as well do you know a document to read about file system tables ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511672/how-can-i-quickly-enumerate-directories-on-win32. Also look for information on accessing and parsing the NTFS Master File Table (MFT).

Comment: Definitely don't recommend parsing NTFS MFT. Have you compared the performance of your code with other programs that iterate over the file system.

Comment: I agree with David Heffernan on not recommending direct NTFS MTF parsing. since this could result in some Anti Virus programs of flagging your application as potentially dangerous. As for your program taking more than 30 seconds to list all files on C drive. Even Windows built in search won't be much faster even thou it is also relying on its search index.

Comment: Coping the file names from the array to the stringlist is useless. You can copy the string array directly to the memo with ``Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(FileNames);``

Comment: Looking up the MFT can be extremely fast. The great tool "Everything" (voidtools.com) does exactly this and finds its results in fractions of a second. However you will need admin privilege to read the MFT tables which is a great drawback for any app on my opinion.

Comment: The allocation overhead is negligible as I commented after measuring in https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-39788

Comment: @StefanGlienke The measurement gives food for thought, but it could still be the case that you were lucky: perhaps there was contiguous memory so that SetLength(x+1) didn't have to copy, and perhaps this coincidence was supported by the fact that you did no other memory allocation inbetween and that the number of files was still fairly small. Just maybe.

Comment: Sure but the point is what I wrote in my first comment on that issue - regardless of how you allocate - the fact that this API is returning a huge array with all elements just to iterate them is bonkers, to begin with.

Comment: Also fwiw there is no maybe about the number of files - I actually wrote the output in my comment about the benchmark and that code is exactly similar to what the code in the question is - there are no allocations "in between" what happens in `GetFiles`. When that code would be executed in a multithreaded application however it would be more visible. Hence my comment about the necessity of an API such as `Directory.EnumerateFiles` in .NET which would be a "for-in"-able wrapper around `FindFirst`/`FindNext`.

Comment: Turning on indexing in Windows can speed things up. See answer from Raymond Chen https://stackoverflow.com/q/15351288/1271778    I've never tried this (nor thought this through) but you could build the file list db yourself and watch folders for changes and update that db, and use only the db to search.  Try indexing in Windows. Also, you've not specified use case - perhaps there's a better way to do what you're actually trying to do (I mean do you really need to search everything under C:\ often?) Oh and finally, you can just exclude C:\Windows in your searches.

Comment: @TByte thanks but I dont know how to use the indexing service ? also how to monitor for file changes ?

Comment: @zac 2nd comment by Raymond Chen is a link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-overview). I never tried it, but there really isn't any magical way to speed things up. I/O is relatively slow.  It's either reading MFT/FAT directly as others suggested (which sounds like a right pain) or, use Windows' built-in Indexing service which I understand has an API. You gotta do some digging if you really want this :)

Answer (score -1):

you could try FilesFound.BeginUpdate. In my test this saved some seconds.

Comment: That would actually be slower because for TStringList the update mechanism does nothing

Comment: Most likely your previous search was cached, making the second "improved" one faster. Test again but restart Windows between each test to avoid falling for false statistics.

Answer (score -1):

Searching through a whole disk is inherently slow, so don't expect miracles. But one bottleneck is the repeated (re)allocation of the dynamic array that TDirectory.GetFiles does (and many other TDirectory methods, too).

I have used the following pattern. It still uses the algorithms of TDirectory (they're convenient!), but avoids its dynamic array. The predicate function is called once for each found file, and by returning False, it tells TDirectory to not do anything with its result array. Instead, I collect the file names myself, in my own (faster) data structure.

(In my real life example, this was not done primarily for speed, but for other reasons, but it increases speed, too, if your own datastructure is fast - for example preallocated, or reallocating itself in larger chunks).

```
uses
  System.IOUtils, System.SysUtils;

var
  PredicateForDestScan: TDirectory.TFilterPredicate;

begin
  PredicateForDestScan := function (const Path: string; const SearchRec: TSearchRec): Boolean
  begin
    if Terminated then
      raise EFastTerminate.Create('');    
    // Always return False. We are not interested in the result array
    // of file names from GetFileSystemEntries, we only want to build up our own data structure.
    Result := False;    
    // Skip system files
    if SearchRec.Attr and faSysFile = 0 then
    begin
      FileName := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Path) + SearchRec.Name;
      // ... Add FileName to your own (fast) datastructure ...
    end;
  end {predicate anonymous function};
  

  TDirectory.GetFileSystemEntries('C:\', TSearchOption.soAllDirectories, PredicateForDestScan);
end;
```

(The Terminated check is because this was run inside a thread, and this way I could cancel out of TDirectory.GetFileSystemEntries.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `FindFirstFileExW` / `FindNextFileW` / `FindClose` recursively - `FindFirstFileExW`  lets you pass `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` (=2) flag as a parameter. It tells Windows that you intend to read all entries in the folder rather than a single match or two.

Also note that it makes sense to parallelize folder processing in case of an SSD drive - if I run 20 threads (equal to the number of cores) on my machine, I process 3,000,000+ files and 400,000+ folders in about 18 seconds on a laptop with a 2 TB SSD drive. In case of an HDD, 1 or 2 threads should be the max as you are limited by the drive head seek times.