# C++ : loop on all files of a folder (and its subdfolders) : simplest solution?

Tags: c++, loops, filesystems, directory, subdirectory

What's the shortest solution to make a loop on all .mp3 files of a folder (and its subdfolders) with C++, OS=Windows?
If possible, I'd like to avoid 3rd party things, such as boost, but if not possible, I'll use these 3rd party things (if easy to install).

Thanks in advance.

(PS: I'm sure this question is very very very common, and surely already answered, but after 10 minutes of search, I haven't found something useful.)

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve? Find all .mp3 on a hard-disk (if so, what do you want to do after that?), or do you have such a list and want to play them (in a loop)? or soemthing else?

Comment: What operating system(s) do you want to target?

Comment: OS=windows,  I'd like to do things related to ID3 tags (with a library for that)   on all MP3 files of D:\MYMUSIC\\*.mp3 (including subfolders)

For an example, putting `std::cout << "MP3 file found: " <<  filename ;` in the loop will be great :)

Comment: I'd probably start with somethign like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2531907/179910 (probably also want to look at the version Billy O'Neal edited into the question).

Comment: which solution is faster ? is boost super fast for listing 15'000 files ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating files in a directory without using FindFirstFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672040/iterating-files-in-a-directory-without-using-findfirstfile)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How might I wrap the FindXFile-style APIs to the STL-style Iterator Pattern in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531874/how-might-i-wrap-the-findxfile-style-apis-to-the-stl-style-iterator-pattern-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

C++ itself have no function for getting files or folders in a folder, since that is OS specific.

Boost would be best if you want cross-platform compatibility, but for windows you could look at the answer here:
[How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

Simply replace

```
printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
```

with a check on the last 4 characters of ent->d_name to see if they are ".mp3" and the do what you want with the file.